# Is there any way that I could get a string without the first char and without having to erase it on C++?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I need to compare my string after the character % which is at the beginning of the sentence to check whether it says 'bold', 'italic', or 'regular'. the code that i have so far is this.

```
#include<iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    
    /*
    int italic = 0;
    int regular = 0;
    int bold = 0;
    */
    int h_tag = 0;
    int total = 0;
    int commands = 0;
    
    ifstream in_file;
    string name_of_file;
    string x;
    
    cout<<"Enter the name of a file to read from: "<<endl;
    cin>> name_of_file;
    in_file.open(name_of_file);
    cout<<endl;
    
    if(!in_file){
        cout<<"File cannot be opened "<< name_of_file << endl;
        exit(1);
    
    }
    
    while(getline(in_file, x)){
        total += 1;
        char letter = x[0];
        if(letter == '#'){
            h_tag += 1;        
        }
        else if(letter == '%'){
            command += 1;
        
        }
     


    }
}
```

Comment: [std::string_view](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view)?

Comment: And if `std::string_view` is too high-tech, begin and end iterators with begin being advanced one character.

Comment: @MooingDuck why would that help? x also has find_first_of?

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe: I stopped reading at "Is there any way that I could get a string without the first char and without having to erase it on C++?", but you're right that in this case, `find_first_of` is sufficient

Comment: Would `std::string::substr()` work? i.e. `x.substr(1)`

Comment: What parts of the standard library are you allowed to use?

Comment: You could also just check with the preceding `%`: `else if(letter == '%') {`  `if (x == "%bold") ...` `if (x == "%italic") ...` etc.

Comment: There is always [std::string::compare](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/compare) -- `if (x.compare(1, x.size(), "italic") == 0) { this is italic...}`

Answer (score 0):

**Use substr function:-**

```cpp
String Y;
Y=name_of_file.substr(1,name_of_file.size()-1);
```

*(Y is the required string)*

Comment: This requires the construction of a temporary string, which is wasteful.  The characters are already available in the original string, so even though this answer may work, it is not very efficient.  Look at [std::string::compare](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/compare).

Comment: `substr(1)` will copy to the end of the string; there’s no need for `size()` gymnastics.